# Как сделать открытие exe приложений в html?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-сайт

Мне на моём сайте нужно открыть приложение.
Но всё, что я находил, просто скачивают уже скачанный файл.

Я понимаю мне нужно вывести такое окно?

[image]

Comment: Это зарегистрированный ранее протокол в системе, при переходе по ссылке вида `discord://` у вас будет запрос на открытие дискорда и других приложений, я не совсем знаю правильное название вашей игры чтобы открыть её, попробуйте разные варианты подстановки чтобы найти верную ссылку

Comment: [Раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38205984/3129992), [два](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2022/01/20/getting-started-url-protocol-handlers-microsoft-edge),  [три](https://dev.to/jamiemcmanus/creating-a-custom-url-protocol-in-net-322h)...

Answer (score 3):

Открыть произвольный exe - никак. Это нарушение безопасности.

Открыть **ссылку** определённого протокола в определённом приложении - можно. Для этого приложение должно зарегистрировать в системе этот протокол.

Например `tg://` откроет telegramm на устройстве где он установлен (и то по запросу как на скрине), `tel://` вызовет звонок в смартфоне и тд,

Comment: Как можно его зарегистрировать?

Comment: Это уже второй вопрос. В смысле что нужно задавать его отдельно. (Но прежде погуглить)